# AutoLayout for UICollectionView Header in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, ios-autolayout

I have created a UICollectionView header using `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` and i provided auto-layout constraints for `UICollectionView` using storyboard but that layout constraint is not working on `CollectionView` Header.

So, my question is how to provide auto-layout constraints to the header.